# menu of gedit on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, gedit

Where is the menu of gedit? It doesn't show up.

Also, as you can see on this image the buttons are gone:
[image]

There are only two buttons here (you can see the "open" button on the image and the "save" button is on the right, which I haven't captured on the image)

How can I search for strings now?

**Edit 1**: As I have discovered, this is also the case for the terminal and nautilus. No menu shows up when I hover over the top. BUT, when turning into a guest session I can correctly see the menus. What is wrong with my old, migrated user?

**Edit 2**: From further testing, I concluded that only the user which ran the upgrade (that is my user) has this problem. All other local users that existed before the upgrade are fine and don't appear to be affected. In addition, the suggested solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1545556) doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532226), which seems to have been there since the `beta2` version of 16.04, as some users [reported](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2319812) in Ubuntu Forums. Its importance has been set to *critical*, so it'll probably be solved soon.

People have reported two different ways to solve this:

- **Temporary fix:** log out and log in
- ***Permanent* fix:**
  fire up a terminal and run the following:

  ```
  $ mkdir -p .config/autostart
  $ gedit .config/autostart/menus.desktop
  ```

  And add to the file this content:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=initctl restart unity-panel-service
  Hidden=false
  NoDisplay=false
  X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
  Name=menus
  Comment=Show me the menus
  X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=
  ```

  `X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=` value is empty on purpose, but if the fix doesn't work properly, you might need to add a 1 or a 2.
  [Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2319736&p=13466716&viewfull=1#post13466716)

Answer (score 0):

I found the desktop entry didn't work on startup (on 16.04). I plagiarised one to come up with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=menus
GenericName=Menus Startup
Comment=Show me the menus
Exec=initctl restart unity-panel-service
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

I also encountered the same issue with LibreOffice which is solved by this fix.

Answer (score -1):

After a fresh & complete re-installation of Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday, I encountered Gedit's missing menu problem for the first time.
Here's what I did to get around it.

Knowing that sudo wasn't doing the job, I thought I'd try it with 'su'.

I gave root a password 
 `sudo passwd root`  (follow the prompts)
then:

> $ su root
>   $ [password for root]
>   $ gedit

Success! root Gedit with all menus present!

To automate it somewhat, I did the following...
Ran **sudo gedit** and saved an **executable** one-liner to **/bin**, named **sugedit**

## !/bin/bash

su -c gedit root

(to make it executable, right-click it in (sudo) Nautilus after you've saved it, and look in **Properties > Permissions**.

Another **sudo gedit** and put a **non-executable, '.desktop'** file in **/usr/share/applications**, called **sugedit.desktop**.

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=sugedit
Comment=Run root as su
GenericName=sugedit
Exec=sugedit
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility
Icon=/mnt/storage2/gnome_furniture/gedit-r.png
NotShowIn=GNOME-Flashback;
X-AppStream-Ignore=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=session-shortcuts`

I don't know how much of that is unnecessary, but who gives a s**t with 2TB of spare storage!?; I just pasted it in from another .desktop file and made the obvious changes. I do KNOW that **'Terminal=true'** is essential because I've not found a way of using **su** as root without having to enter the root password, and it needs the terminal for that to happen. I also pointed **'Icon='** to one I'd been using before.

**sugedit** is now visible in the dash and I dragged a copy down to the launcher.

The terminal window remains open in the background, but it closes when you close Gedit.

I hope it works for you!

Now I just need to get user options ('Open with', etc.) onto the context menu in Nautilus/Files running as root.

N.B.
I downloaded the source code for Gedit-3.33.90 from the developer's site, but compilation failed due to a missing file.